# Conditional query using jq

Tags: json, select, jq

I have the following JSON data

```
[
    {
        "id": "001",
        "repoTags": {
            "docker/alpine": {
                "2.1.9": {
                    "vulnerable": "true",
                    "vulnerabilityCount": 19
                },
                "stable": {
                    "vulnerable": "true",
                    "vulnerabilityCount": 19
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "002",
        "repoTags": {
            "docker/alpine": {
                "3.0.0": {
                    "vulnerable": "false",
                    "vulnerabilityCount": 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to get the value of the field `id`, but only for the element which has `repoTags` = "3.0.0".
Is there any way to do this conditional query using jq? If not, what alternative do you propose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a filter I think will help

```
.[] | select(.repoTags | any(keys[] == "3.0.0")) | .id
```

with your input it produces

```
"002"
```

If you don't want the extra quotes in the output you can use the `-r` option.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZFND4IgGMfvfArGSbdGaCfbOvUVujkPpNRIpgbY5qrPTog22@SQW@s5MHh@/@eVy9UYnGbwARUTLNcBlqypD/SsrItWXVCyTlm@20G0wQQTFIaWYF4YkwJo7e7O3hAv0BYiQiK0mpzvfBZNUkeKOi@ZXFPR8IrNsJPEOMKJFzl8a0XFJD2KPhxp2bKPyl4lF1x3@7qttI2Ikpn4OY9HSo8V/tcF8L@G29ijZ/HxzxY//PWXI5@oUMtmJktHBhl4AQ)

Comment: Not sure the behavior of `any` is defined when the condition filter emits a stream. Just tested and I am having wrong results with both jq 1.5 and 1.6 depending on the order of input items (try `jq -n '[[1,2],[1]] | any(.[] == 1)'` for an example). It seems fixed in the master version but I don't know if it is just luck on my examples or an actual recent fix. In doubt, I'd suggest `select(.repoTags | any(has("3.0.0")))` as a safer alternative.